# LOCAL MS ACCESS Database Sync Operation to a CLOUD Backend W/ Poor Internet

Tags: ms-access, database-design, ms-access-2016, connectivity

**Background**

We use MS Access to manage some of our work, but often times our operations are in highly remote locations where cell or sat signal are the most reliable forms of connectivity.  But the service isn't fantastic.  Coverage will drop sometimes (more often than not) in the middle of an update.

**Setup**

Current set up has a Backend File which stores only the tables and a few simple routines that is stored on a cloud based server and a Frontend File that is stored on the user's machine.  In order to make updating and usage of the system even feasible we had to create copies of the tables on the Frontend so that the user could run updates effectively then provided a sync button that essentially just appends the information from the Local Table to the Cloud Table.  Otherwise the user would have to wait for the server to respond with each entry which was extremely slow.

**Problem**

However, nearly anytime they run this process it stops in the update and corrupts the file.  So we switched to just using a simple excel export that they can then email to the main office and someone at the office imports the file to update their local tables and syncs to the Cloud Tables in the Backend File.

**General Notes**

I believe we've narrowed it down to being an issue with MS ACCESS and poor internet connectivity, because all systems work when the internet connection is even just reasonably decent.  Are there any work arounds available that will resolve this issue?

Comment: A file based (Access) backend isn't going to work for this scenario. You should switch to a server based backend, e.g. SQL Server Express (free). Updates will be faster and reliable.

Comment: Thanks for the intel Andre I'll give it a shot and post back what I did.

Comment: testing an AZURE SQL database on different connections presently.  I'll let you know how it goes.